How can console version of app access settings of MSIX UI version of app?
I have a UI application that also has a separate console version. I'm looking at changing the main UI application to MSIX deployment (with potential future deployment to MS Store). The console version of the application will remain non-MSIX (I think that it's not possible for the console app to be MSIX anyway). The question is how can the console version continue to access the options that are set in the UI application since MSIX means that the options are stored in a sandboxed location?
The console app just needs to read the options set in the UI application - it doesn't need to modify them.
I'm open to including the console application in the MSIX package, if that's possible. To be clear, suppose my UI app is "Foo", I want a separate "FooConsole" which performs the basic logic of "Foo" without the UI, but accessing the options set in "Foo". This is currently working without MSIX, but I want MSIX since the eventual goal is the Microsoft Store.

You can keep the console application in the MSIX container too. To make it visible via command line you need to declare an AppExecutionAlias in your package manifest.
Here are more details (scroll down to the appexecutionalias section): https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-environment-variables.html
You can do this in tools like Advanced Installer but you can also manually add it in your manifest if you build the MSIX package with the basic support from Visual Studio.
EDIT: @Dave Doknjas confirms in one of the comments below that the Windows App Certification process limits us to one app in an msix package, within the Microsoft Store.
Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.

So you can have a UI application combined with a separate console application in the same MSIX package? Your link talks about launching the UI application, but I need a separate console application which accesses the settings of the UI application.

you can have as many applications as you want inside the same MSIX, with GUI and without. If they are all in the same container they will be able to easily share the same settings (files and registry hives)
For the console application just declare an appexecutionalias so you can call it via the command line, otherwise the OS will not make it visible outside the container.

But I thought you couldn't have a default app for an MSIX bundle - this is from an Advanced Installer article: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/faq-msix.html#:~:text=When%20you%20install%20a%20multi,app%20for%20an%20MSIX%20bundle. I want the main UI to be the default and the console app is a supplementary tool.

I see now that I can select "view code" and see the underlying xml. However, even though I've added 2 projects to the WAP project (the UI app and the console app), there's only one application in the Applications section with an application id of "App".

Going through the Windows App Certification process now and have confirmed that you cannot have more than one app in an msix package within the Microsoft Store. So the UI app and the console app have to be in separate msix packages!
